# A situation where ignoring clustering optimises the Type I and Type II error rates?

Tags: clustering, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am interested in modelling clustered data with a small number of clusters as follows:

$$Y_{ij} = β_0 + β_1X + u_i + e_{ij}$$

(where $_i$ = 1 to 3; $_j$ = 1 to 12); $Y_{ij}$ is our normally distributed outcome variable; $X$ is a binary categorical variable = 0, 1 with n = 6 in each group. 
The variance at level 1 is modeled as: $e $~$ N(0, σ_e^2)$. 
The variance at level 2 is modeled as: $u $~$ N(0, σ_u^2)$.

We have a balanced design and no missing data.
If we run this as a linear mixed model, say with the nlme package in R or xtmixed in Stata, we face the issue of how many degrees of freedom we apply to the associated t-value of Group 0 compared to Group 1. Because we have a balanced design with a cluster-invariant regressor, the quotient of our parameter estimate and its standard error estimate has a t-distribution, but the associated degrees of freedom is not a trivial problem and I note that the latest lme4 package (from Doug Bates et al.) in R does not actually report p values for this reason. 
The nlme output will give us 32 degrees of freedom, and because we have a balanced design, gives exactly the same result as a “repeated measures” ANOVA model.  But for a small number of clusters this will inflate the Type I error.

In fact, on running simulations of this approach we find that the Type I error rate is not well contained below 0.05 (although generally not exceeding 0.10, regardless of the intraclass correlation).
An alternative is to use Stata’s approach to clustered regression and use G – 1 = 2 degrees of freedom. This approach nicely contains the Type I error to < 0.05.
Or even more conservatively, to use G – L degrees of freedom where L is the number of cluster-invariant regressors, including the constant, so giving 1 degree of freedom on the T.

Another alternative would be to run this as a simple OLS regression ignoring clustering.
Generally, this approach would be considered naïve and inappropriate; however, in this situation, we have the interesting result that the standard error on the regression parameter estimate is increased with OLS compared to the mixed model estimates (because we are making a within-cluster comparison). And even with 34 degrees of freedom we find that the Type I error is well contained below 0.05 regardless of the ICC.

On modelling the [power analysis of various approaches,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9du2.jpg) we find that the linear mixed model performs best, as expected, but recall that it does not contain the Type I error.
The OLS approach is next best and nicely contains the Type I.

Given that simulation studies demonstrate that the Type I error is well contained to < 0.05 by OLS regression and it has reasonable power, is OLS regression analysis a reasonable and defendable approach in this situation?